# Comparison bewteen types in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I found this code (on HTML5), and there is nothing wrong with it, it work just fine, but i dont get the whole process it make(the code create a virtual keyboard that writes on a textfield the letters you click) 
the part i dont get it:

```
var i,c;

function init(){

i=document.getElementById('keyboard').getElementsByTagName('input');

for(c=0;c<i.length;c++) {

    if(i[c].type==='button') {

         i[c].addEventListener('onclick',makeClickHandler(c));

       }

}
```

My mains doubt are the i[c]
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a JavaScript code, not HTML5 code.

Comment: This is not html. Please, mark the correct tag.

Comment: It gets all `<input>` within the `keyboard` element, loops through them, and if they're `type="button"`, it adds the click handler to them.

Comment: `i` is the most innacurate (stu...) name to give to a variable that actually represents a collection of DOM elements. We're writing code for humans, not for machines. Machines are doing just fine

Comment: "My main doubts are the `i[c]`"  I have no idea what your issue is from this statement.  Please elaborate on what you find confusing.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan And then to take that and use it in a `for` loop of all places... eek!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t8704hna/  Also not sure how this code is working binding for an 'onclick' event....

Answer (score 0):

```
var i,c; // global var declaration usually not clever

    function init(){ // he creates a js function

     var keyboardelement=document.getElementById('keyboard'); 
     var inputfield=keyboardelement.getElementsByTagName('input');
     for( var c=0;c<inputfield.length;c++) {

         if(inputfield[c].type==='button') { // he runs over the dom tree 
            //    under keyboard to find his buttons...
           // now he adds on each of the buttons a OWN click handler which 
            //calls the 
            //    routine "makeClickHandler" -wrong wording should be known as 
            //   ClickHandler or maybee not s below

            inputfield[c].addEventListener('onclick',makeClickHandler(c));

          }

     }
```

that is what he made and what i call not that clever cause now he has to implement or make for each button own routine to handle this. Maybee that is why he chose the wording makeclickhanler cause h creates them dynamically.

This here do it all including the evnet handler a "nice" display and a bit action. It will display the text you click together.

```
     <html><body>
     <form name="keyboard">  
        //could also be dynamically created but...
        <div id="out"><div>
        <input type="button" value="a" class="kbdbutton">
        <input type="button" value="b" class="kbdbutton">
        <input type="button" value="c" class="kbdbutton">
        <input type="button" value="d" class="kbdbutton">
     </form>
```

usually i would add also a ID attribute but

```
  <script>
    // get all buttons in one call
    var kbd_btn=documentGetElementsByClassName("kbdbutton")

    for (var i=0; I< kbd_btn.length;i++){
      kbd_btn[i].id = kbd_btn[i].value;
    }
   // NOW every key has its own *corresponding* id free of charge 
   // which also makes the button interesting for a global event handler

   // act like a man and use ONE handler
        document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {}

             var id=event.target.id;
             if (id){  // not all click events have a id
                console.log(id);

               display=document.getElementById("out")

                switch(id) {
                  case "a":
                     alert("a clicked")
                  case default:
                 display.innerHTML=display.innerHTML+id;
                }

        }
        )
       </script>
   </body></html>
```

if i would a just few lines more and use the evil eval function i would have a nice complete pocket calculator...